# Route Passing a value

Tags: php, laravel-4

newbie in laravel.

In laravel sample routing

```
Route::get('books/{genre}', 'controller@method');
```

The link would be something like this

`link.com/books/crime` or `link.com/books/programming`

how do i do it if I want to get both  genre?

if this possible is to achieve

```
link.com/books?genre=crime,programming
```

how do i write that in routes? and also how do i get the value in controller?

I have tried something like this. But I don't have any idea how to achieve it.

```
Route::get('books?{genre?}', 'controller@method');
```

Controller part

```
function method($fields = null) {
    return jsonData;
}
```

**Found a way but its kinda awful...**

route

```
Route::get('books', 'controller@method');
```

url

```
link.com/books?genre=crime,programming,love,religion
```

method

```
function method() {
     $array = explode(',',$_GET['fields');
     //.....
     return jsonData;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways you can achieve that.

if want to achieve,

```
http://link.com/books/crime/programming
```

or

```
http://link.com/books/crime
```

you can use the following routes:

```
Route::get('books/{genre}/{genreOptional?}', function($genre, $genreOptional = null)
{
    dd($genre, $genreOptional);
});
```

or

```
Route::get('books/{genre}/{genreOptional?}', 'controller@method' );
```

Your controller:

```
public function method($genre, $genreOptional = NULL)
{
   //
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but i want to get an array of genre.

Comment: nope..just the url. it will return a json data based on the array given..im building an api for my project so i can use it easily..

Comment: If you want an array it think its better to put this in a querystring or separate the genres with something like |